# Riemann Integration on a Jordan Region problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The problem is stated as follows:

> Assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $E = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $f(x,y) + f(y,x) = 1$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$.  Find the integral of $f$ over $E$.

Now, I can show that $\int_{E} (f(x,y) + f(y,x))\space dV = \int_E1\space dx$ = Vol$(E) = 1$.  Thus, by the linear properties of integrals, we have that $\int_{E} f(x,y) \space dV$ $+ \space$ $\int_{E} f(y,x) \space dV = 1 = f(x,y) + f(y,x).$

Do my above observations amount to anything?

Comment: Try showing that $\int_E f(x,y)$ and $\int_E f(y,x)$ relate in some way.

Comment: Well, intuitively, I suspect that $\int_{E} f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} = \int_{E} f(y,x)$

Comment: What happens if you consider the change of variables $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
 try to change of variable :
$(x,y)$ to $(y,x)$